# jquery next() this

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I stumpled upon a small problem.

Trying to make an easy accordian nav. with jquery, but noticed something I cannot figure out.

here's my code

```
<div class="box"> Item 1</div>
<div class="text"> Text Box </div>
<div class="box"> Item 2</div>
<div class="text"> Text Box 2</div>
<div class="box"> Item 3</div>
<div class="text"> Text Box 3</div>
```

JS

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $('.text').slideUp()
    $(this).next().slideToggle()    
})
```

What I wonder is, if I use

```
    $(this).next().slideToggle()
```

*everything works fine.*

Now I tried to replace (this) as following:

```
    $('.text').next().slideToggle()
```

But the effect is different.
I thought (this) would be related to the div-text or at least to something else in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$(this)` in the click event represent the source of event, on the other hand  `$('.text')` represents collection of all the elements those have `class` text.   `$('.text').next().slideToggle()` will call the `slideToggle` on the first element of collection returned by selector `$('.text')`.

Comment: thank you for your quick replay and your great answer.
But didn't you mean that with your last sentence

 $(this).next().slideToggle() will call the slideToggle on the first element of collection returned by selector $('.text')

?

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
$(this) // <----Represents current target which got the event
```

while:

```
$('.text') // <--- this is a collection of all elems with class '.text' so all
           // -----will be getting events simultaneosly.
```